# Apply discount if 2 of the same item from a category are added

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I searched SO for this but all I could find is apply discount on items from a category. But I want to apply discount only if the items are from a category say "15% discount category" and if the customer order the same product.

Ex. - Lets assume we have Product A, B & C in a category id 442.
Now if I add ***2 of A*** & ***1 of B*** in cart it applies discount like -

```
A(2) - 15% discount
B(1) - 15% discount
```

I want it to be like this -

```
A(2) - 15% discount
B(1) - no discount
```

Current Conditions are -

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
   If total quantity  equals or greater than  2  for a subselection of
                      items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
   Category  is  442
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Action tab and try this -

> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
>
> > Quantity in cart  equals or greater than  2

Comment: I did that under Action tab and It worked.